# markdown to Html ReactJs

Tags: html, reactjs, markdown

Как в ReactJs Маркдаун перевести в HTML?

Answer (score 1):

есть готовый компонент для этого:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactMarkdown = require('react-markdown');

var input = '# This is a header\n\nAnd this is a paragraph';

ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactMarkdown source={input} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown